# Least value of $\sum_{cyc} \sec^2\frac{A}{2}$ in a triangle

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

The question is, for a triangle $ABC$, we need to find the least value of $$\sum_{cyc} \sec^2\frac{A}{2}$$

The solution is as follows:

[image]

However, I don't understand why is it that we are concluding in the end that the triangle has to be an equilateral triangle. The solution says for the equality to hold, we need to have $A=B=C$ but I don't get why.

Comment: Because the equality condition of the $AM-GM$ inequality, $$\frac{x_{1}+x_{2}+\cdots+x_{n}}{n} \geq \sqrt[n]{x_{1} \cdot x_{2} \cdots x_{n}}$$
only holds when:
$$x_{1}=x_{2}=\cdots =x_{n}$$

Comment: Oh okay thanks!